# UITest localized application

Tags: ios, swift, localization, xcode-ui-testing

I have an application in French only.
In the storyboard, I have a mix of specifics and system buttons.

When launched on a french device, all is good, the system buttons have french names.

I added the arguments passed on launch in my unique sheme

> -AppleLanguages (French)
>
> -AppleLocale fr_FR

so, when launched on the simulator, I have the same result than on a french device.

But when I want to test with UITests, the system buttons have english name (ie Edit/Done), so my tests with tap on button "Modifier" or "Ok" doesn't work.

Is there a way to force the device language before testing the application, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a good solution for this problem.

But I saw that the setting doesn't change between two launches of the iPhone emulator. So I changed the iPhone language to French, and it will be OK until I change the simulator's model or I localize the application for another language.